# Control Amazon Alexa via Raspberry Pi

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit

I want to integrate Amazon Alexa in my current Smart Home setup.

The main function that I would like to have is control the volume and play and pause music (for an alarm clock like function). I am not able to find such an API.

I am planing to controll Amazon Alexa (Dot) via an Raspberry Pi.

Does anyone know such an API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has not publicly released an API to control Alexa enabled devices as of now.

If you look at the Amazon Alexa's IFTT page, there are no actions:
https://ifttt.com/amazon_alexa (scroll down to and click, show more actions and triggers). Quite a few triggers are available, but no actions, which is what you are interested in currently.

The closest you could get is by hacking into the network using Wireshark, figure out what messages are sent by Alexa to Echo when volume up/down commands are given. But that is again over a TLS connection, so you wouldn't get anything.